# Why would this session != params trip in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, csrf

I am using Sinatra and using the sinatra-authentication gem for authentication, along with custom forms such as a contact form.

To help resolve CSRF issues I devised a little solution which would work with predefined routes from sinatra-authentication as well as custom routes.

```
before do
  if request.post?
    if session[:csrf] != params[:csrf]
      halt 503, erb('<h1>500: oops</h1>')
    end
  end 

  time = Time.now.to_s
  @key = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(time)
  session[:csrf] = @key
end
```

So on each page request it sets a session which is a hash of the current time. This hash is also set to each form using a hidden element `<input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="<%= @key %>" />`. When the form is submitted, within the original `before` it checks the item stored in the session with the item submitted as a hidden value. Simple!

But... this works fine on localhost, fine on my herokuapp.com domain, and fine on my `www` domain (which is a cname of the herokuapp.com domain), but it does not work on the `non-www` domain (which is an A record for the Heroku set of IPs).

The only difference I can see is the `non-www` domains with the A record in the DNS seem to be getting varnish headers set, so must be going through varnish somewhere, but as the session is within a rack.session I am wondering if Varnish is filtering this out.

So ultimately, why is `if session[:csrf] != params[:csrf]` returning `true`?

Comment: It shouldn't be. I don't have a last-modified or etag header set. For some reason these two values don't always match. Wondering if trying `<input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="<%= session[:csrf] %>" />` in the view would make any difference, but it shouldn't. Although this would help if the issue is something getting stuck in the session.

Comment: May I suggest [Rack CSRF](https://rubygems.org/gems/rack_csrf) as an alternative? I've never had any problems with it.